# Multiple worded cell contents put into one cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, google-spreadsheets

I am making a pricing sheet and I currently have this formula
=IF(B1>0,A1,"")
With this formula the contents of A1 might say something like "Apple" and B1 is the quantity, so as long as it's greater than zero it will show up in the cell that this formula is in.
I want to make a formula that would be able to take the cell contents of not only A1 but A2 (Banana), A3 (Orange), A4 (Lemon) and A5 (Tomato) and if the value of the B column beside any of those is greater than 1 then it puts these into a cell together, so if B1, B3 and B5 all had a value greater than 1 it would say "Apple + Orange + Tomato" is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

if you are using Office 2019/365, please try this:

```
=TEXTJOIN("+",1,IF(B1:B5>1,A1:A5,""))
```

[image]

Comment: This looks like it should work but I'm using Google Sheets! Is there an equivalent formula?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

In A1, A2,...Apple, Banana,....
In B1, B2, B3, 1,0,3,...

Step 1. Enter formula in Cell  C1 = IF(B1>0,A1, "").
Copy formula, down the row, in C2,C3,...

Step 2. Enter formula in Cell  D1 = C1

Enter formula in Cell  D2 = IF(C2="", D1,  D1 & " + " & C2)
( Concatenation )

Copy formula, of Cell D2, down the row, in D3, D4,...

Step 3. In Cell E1 enter the formula E1 = D5 ( Last Cell )
just to display the Answer.
You can hide column D, to bring clarity.

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for this. This should work okay but would there be any way to do all of this with a single formula?